# Inductive effect on stability of free radical

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrons, stability, radicals

How does inductive effect affect the stability of free radical?

I can't seem to understand whether the carbon with the odd electron is deficient or not.

That is, whether a +I group, like alkyl, will stabilize it or not? I know that an adjacent alkyl group like $\ce{-CH3}$ will anyway stabilize it by hyperconjugation.

Comment: Generally, we consider radicals to be electron deficient species.

Comment: +I groups stabilize free radical and -I groups destabilize free radical.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/164828

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - Free radicals, which are carbon intermediates with an extra electron, are stabilized by electron-donating groups and destabilized by electron-withdrawing groups.

---

**Explanation:**

1. **Stability Factors:** Free radicals, being electron-deficient, benefit from neighboring atoms providing electron density. The more alkyl groups present on the carbon, the greater the stability, following the order: $\mathrm{\dot{C}H_3 < 1^\circ < 2^\circ < 3^\circ}$.

   [image: Stability order of free radicals]

---

2. **Electron Configuration:** Analyzing the electrons in an alkyl free radical reveals three bonding pairs and one unpaired electron. This results in a trigonal pyramidal geometry due to hybridization to an $\mathrm{sp^3}$ state.

   [image: Carbon free radical resonance]

---

3. **Delocalization (Resonance):** Similar to carbocations, delocalization or resonance plays a role in stabilizing free radicals.

---

**Sources:** NCERT, class notes, and [Master Organic Chemistry](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/08/02/3-factors-that-stabilize-free-radicals/#one).